# How to change the GoogleMapsZoomLevel to a textbox instead of the slider

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have two different installs of Orchard CMS.  In one install, the Map type has a text box for GoogleMapsZoomLevel and in the other it has a slider.  My client has complained that the slider is not intuitive and has requested that all instances of Map type use the text box.

I have went over the type and all the settings are the same.

Here is the definition in the Map type of both instances:
[image]

[image]

And this is how they render when you create a new "Map"

[image]
[image]

Take note of the slider for the zoom level.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare the rendered html, and if there are any errors while serving the resources (css, scripts). Probably one instance is missing a script library, or has a different template.

Comment: After viewing the source, I noticed that the input with the slider is type="range".  This tells me that something is making Orchard render that control differently.

Comment: Yes, something is making Orchard rendering differently, exactly why I am suggesting you to check the templates. By the way there is no such "range" attribute usage by default in Orchard. You should check any file named of Numeric.Edit.cshtml.

Comment: Thank you.  The file Numeric.Edit.cshtml did contain code to add in the "range" property.